# Why does stripVersion not work on maven-dependency-plugin with mojo unpack-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Im trying to unpack dependencies with `maven-dependency-plugin:unpack-dependencies`.
According to their [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html), it should support `stripVersion`.

Excerpt of my POM:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>**/*.yaml</includes>               
              <includeGroupIds>com.foo.group</includeGroupIds>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
              <stripVersion>true</stripVersion> <!-- doesnt have any effect -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The dependencies gets unpacked, but not in the desired folder structure.

This is what I get

```
/test-classes/META-INF/<group>/<artifactId>/<version>/files...
```

This is what I need, at least

```
/test-classes/META-INF/<group>/<artifactId>/files...
```

When I use `stripVersion` on `maven-dependency-plugin:copy` mojo, it does what the docs are stating, copying the mentioned dependency and stripping off the version from the resulting jarfile.

Can anyone shed some light, why stripVersion is not working on `unpack-dependencies` or what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you like to unpack dependencies within your build? What kind of project is this? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I already found a way to bypass my issue. The basic motivation was collecting stubs (`spring-cloud-contracts`) on the classpath, parse appropriate parts (request / response bodies) of it to have a convenient way to generate mock objects (used to mock service layer) directly from stubs - But would be still interested, whats wrong with my above mentioned approach or better said - why stripversion is not doing what Ive expected